# Regex for search, a more refined fuzzy search

Tags: javascript, regex, search, full-text-search

I have the generic fuzzy search right now, so that if type "a" it'll return me every word that contains an A. However I want a more refined search that does this.

For example I have the word: **'Frankster Muniz'**

searching "frank","fr","f", "mun", "m" will indeed return 'Frankster Muniz'

searching "rank","ster","r", "niz" will not return anything

it must match the first beginning words,I have no idea where to start here. I am very new to regex. Thank you

Comment: What is about your try? Post your regex-expression to look, what's running wrong.

Comment: something like `/\bfrank/i` ? aka: `RegExp("\\b" + term, "i")` passes your tests

Comment: If you want to match a complete word, use `RegExp(\`\\b${search}\\w*\`, 'i')` - don't forget to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) `'search'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could begin with this:

If `input` is user-input and `name` is name on database ,

```js
var name = "Frankster Muniz";
var input = "Frank";

function match(name,input){
var matched = 0;
if(name.match(new RegExp("\\b"+input+".*","i")))
  matched=1;
return matched;
}

console.log(match(name,"Frank"));
console.log(match(name,"ster"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start matching at the beginning of words by using the word boundary character `\b`. So the power of the regex becomes:

```
new RegExp(`\\b${input}`, 'i');
```

Check out the interactive example:

```js
let names = [
  'Frankster Muniz',
  'Sarah Walin',
  'Tyler Robinson',
  'Ronald Muniz'
];

let results = document.querySelector('#results');
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  findUsers(this.value);
});

buildList(names);

function findUsers(input) {
  let reg = new RegExp(`\\b${input}`, 'i');
  let found = names.filter(name => reg.test(name));
  buildList(found);
}

function buildList(names) {
  let html = '';
  names.forEach(name => html += `<li>${name}</li>`);
  results.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<label>Filter:</label>
<input id="search">
<br><br>
<div>Names:</div>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```